# Binding to a Runtime Defined User Control's Dependency Property

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have noticed there are a lot of dependency property questions. I am hoping this is different enough that it's worth asking. I'm also willing to admit I may just be taking the wrong approach.

I am currently tasked with creating a search window with a custom search parameters user control. The idea being that you have the user control do your search and determine search parameters, and the search results are displayed on a GridView of the main window. So the basic problem is that I have an ObservableCollection in the user control's view model that is defined as a dependency property, and I need to bind the main window's DataGrid to that ObservableCollection. To add a final layer of complexity, the user control for the window is determined at runtime by passing it into the window's constructor.

DataSearchBase.xaml.cs

```
    public DataSearchBase(BaseUserSearch us)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            userSearchControl = us;

            SetSearchUserControl();
            ResetTitle();
            SetupGridColumns();
        }

        private void SetSearchUserControl()
        {
            Grid.SetRow(userSearchControl, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(userSearchControl, 0);
            SearchGrid.Children.Add(userSearchControl);


            DataContext = userSearchControl;
        }
```

Note that I set the data context for the base window to the userSearchControl

DataSearchBase.xaml

```
<DVD:SimpleEditWindowBase 
    x:Class="DVDLibrary.View.DataSearchBase"
    xmlns:DVD="clr-namespace:DVDLibrary.View"
    x:Name="DataSearch_frm">
...
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Name="searchResultsGrid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UserSearch,Path=DataContext.SearchResults, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Note that this is where I attempt to set the ItemsSource binding to the SearchResults dependency property of the UserControl's view model.

DVDSearch.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="DVDLibrary.View.DVDSearch"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DVDLibrary.View"         
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DVDLibrary.ViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="UserSearch"
>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:DVDSearchControlViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</local:BaseUserSearch>
```

Notice that I have set the name of the user control, and its data context to my view model.

My DVDSearch.xaml.cs is empty besides the InitializeComponent().

DVDSearchControlViewModel.cs

```
class DVDSearchControlViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DVDSearchControlViewModel()
    {
        //base
        SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnSearch, CanSearch);

        SearchResults = dvdList.DVDs; //a populated list of my DVDModel class.
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchResultsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchResults",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<DVDModel>), typeof(DVDSearchControlViewModel),
        new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DVDModel>()));

    public ObservableCollection<DVDModel> SearchResults
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DVDModel>)this.GetValue(SearchResultsProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SearchResultsProperty, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand<object> SearchCommand { get; private set; }

    private void OnSearch(object arg)
    {
        var results = (from DVD in DVDs
                       where DVD.TypeOfDisk == DiskType.DiskTypeID
                       select DVD).ToList();

        foreach (DVDModel model in results)
        {
            SearchResults.Add(model);
        }
    }

    private bool CanSearch(object arg)
    {

        if (DiskType == null && Director == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that the searchResultsGrid on the DataSearchBase window is not binding to the SearchResults of the DVDSearchControlViewModel. All other binding is working, and the SearchResults is filled both during the constructor and during the OnSearch method (as in it's being updated).

Thanks for reading through my question. I know it's slightly verbose, and don't hesitate to tell me if I just have a really basic concept wrong. I just need to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Is the debug-output saying something about the binding? Maybe complaining, that it's not possible to resolve element named 'UserSearch', since that's possibly defined within another XAML Namescope?